# Oracle 12C compatability with Sonar 4.3.2

Tags: sonarqube

Our DB team is upgrade Oracle to 12C. We currently have Sonar 4.3.2. Is Sonar 4.3.2 compatible with Oracle 12C.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open ticket on the matter and no support yet: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6768

No roadmap is defined, but support might very much not comes first with oldest versions of SQ, upgrade to latest LTS version or latest version might be required.